# Keyboard shortcut to select multiple lines in Xcode

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, xcode

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select lines e.g. 23-47 in an Xcode editor? Command-I works to select the current line and command-l to navigate to a line.

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple lines one at a time by using general mac shortcut.
<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>

After one line is selected, keep pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>

Comment: How about for specific line numbers?

Comment: Select line(with specific number): cmd-L